# Jquery lightbox is not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I am currently using prettyPhoto lightbox for my images and for some reason i cant get it to work. I know this is a very basic questions but some help would be appreciated. i found the script here:http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

Additionally here is the page i am trying to get it to work on:

http://obliqueinteractive.com/creative/work.html

I have read the documentation carefully still am not getting anything. I dont know am i missing something?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Do you have jquery linked up?  I don't see it in your head. I see you have the jquery prettyPhoto plugin but not the actual jquery file. Like firebug says it is dieing at the $ what is your document ready.

Answer (score 2):

You have to include jQuery in `head` section. You probably forgot about it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did not even know they released jquery 1.4!

Answer (score 0):

Your prettyPhoto script `js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js` script is throwing a 404 too.

Answer (score 0):

So I visited that page, and immediately in the FireFox Error Console I got a "$ is not defined" message.

You're missing a `<script>` element which loads the jQuery libraries... you have a  element which refers to 'js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js', but when I try to follow that path I get a 404.

So; uplaod jQuery core js file to server; add `<script>` with 'src' attribute which points to jQuery core, then find out where 'jquery.prettyPhoto.js' is and make sure the 'src' attribute the `<script>` which is already there matches its location.